# Web GUI for custom/predefined SQL queries

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, report

Before reinvent the wheel i want to ask stackoverflow community to recommend me a tool which can solve one very common (probable) problem:

I have a set of SQL queries with changeable parameters like this:

```
SELECT title, author, created_at 
FROM books
WHERE created_at BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date> ;
```

And I need a tool (preferable web application) which will allow me to see the results of this query by 
changing parameters from GUI (Datepickers, Textboxes e.t.c.) without changing the query template or programm code.
Export the results into csv or xls will be fine too.

I know some tools like PHPMyAdmin which are good for geeks - not for non qualified users and unsafe generally.

Very close to the thing i want is: https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder
but it very restrictive to what kinds of queries i can use because of ORM bounds

Comment: I think you are wrong with phpmyadmin, is safe at dev/stage environments, easy and intuitive, and if you are using linux, really easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too keen on many out-of-the-box web solutions... beyond ones like phpMyAdmin... which you have already mentioned as being less than ideal for your situation.

There are however, some other tools that may work.

[DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/).  This tool allows for parameterization of values within queries.  I use this tool religously for assorted database tasks.  It is nice because it works with multiple DBMS.  It may not, however, restrict access to modifying queries like you may need.... and is more developer/sql-saavy friendly than it is every day user friendly.

Another option, which I am not sure if you have considered, is using [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/connect-to-a-postgresql-database-HA104028095.aspx) itself and defining your own workbooks that have the queries parameterized.  This may be the most use-able for every day users... but would require some up-front development on your part. If you are willing to spend the time, this may be the cleanest for your end users.  You can:

1. Hide/protect the queries themselves from the users, and only expose
   the data you want them to be able to parameterize.
2. Format the returned data for whatever reports you are generating.
3. Have the data already in an Excel table format, to allow for additional sorting and filtering.

These may be options you have already considered... but figured I'd throw them out there.. just in case.